# Why does the Pythagorean Theorem not work on this problem in the way that I used it?

Tags: geometry

To begin with, I apologize for the vagueness of my question. It's hard to explain what exactly my question entails without seeing what process I went through to try to solve the problem. My question is just that I don't understand why my method did not work.

**The problem**

In Figure, $\mathrm{P}$ is a point in the square of side-length $10$ such that it is equally distant from two consecutive vertices and from the opposite side $\mathrm{AD}$. What is the length of $\mathrm{BP}$?

(A) 5

(B) 5.25

(C) 5.78

(D) 6.25

(E) 7.07

(I apologize for the crude drawing, the problem was in my book so I had to improvise using Paint.)

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCAdX.png)

**What I did**: Since $\mathrm{BC}$ and $\mathrm{CD}$ are both $10$, I used the Pythagorean Theorem to get the length of diagonal $\mathrm{BD}$ as $\sqrt{200}$ and divide it by $2$. My answer was therefore **(E) 7.07**.

**What my book did**: Let $\mathrm{T}$ be the midpoint of $\mathrm{AB}$. Set $\mathrm{BP}$ to $x$, and the length of $\mathrm{BT}$ to $10-x$. To complete the triangle, they set the length of $\mathrm{PT}$ to $5$. Then they used the Pythagorean Theorem to do $x^2 = (10-x)^2 + 5^2$, yielding an answer of **(D) 6.25**.

While I understand how they did it, I simply cannot understand why my method didn't work. Is there some law that I'm not aware of pertaining to this problem? Since my incorrect answer was an answer choice, I assume there is a common error I'm making that was set as a trap.

Could someone explain this to me? Thank you very much.

Comment: It is because $BP$ does not lie on the diagonal of the square. In fact, if that was the case, that would be $10\sqrt{2} /2$ long, but $P$ would be the center of the square, making the third segment long $5$ and thus different from the other two.

Comment: @Harnak, was just going to say this. Nice.

Comment: @Harnak OH that was very careless of me to assume that BP is the same length as PD. It makes sense now, thank you!

Comment: @ak_27, it is awesome that you came to this website for help with this. most people would just get frustrated and give up. keep at it! i loved this question. very subtle.

Comment: You're welcome ^^

Comment: emphasis slightly different, your answer assumes BPC is a right angle, which is how your diagram appears to the eye. Since you know how to draw thing, maybe you can draw the diagram closer to the proportions that actually come out. The experience will be worthwhile.

Comment: @WillJagy My apologies. The drawing was quite similar to the one in the book. I believe it was meant to confuse in the first place.

Comment: Understood. I am encouraging you to make a drawing that does not deceive the eye. I get BPC about $106^\circ$ rather than $90^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

The diagram in correct proportion. To get the square edge length $10,$ multiply all lengths by $$ \frac{10}{8} =  \frac{5}{4} = 1.25  $$

[image]